# Java - Transferring big files over channels - NIO

Tags: java, nio

I have to transfer ~100MB of data over ServerSocket using NIO, but I can't figure out how to do this without transfer breaking at any place / keeping the state of transfer.

My first idea was to send the size of file, apparently I can't send size of that big files because it wont even fit on RAM at once. Then I thought, why not just transfer til nothing is received, but thats when problem comes in.

Even if I am writing server-sided data all the time

```
        FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(f).getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        while(fc.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            while(channel.write(buffer) > 0);
            buffer.clear();
        }
```

but because there have to be breaks in file transfer some time reading the data constantly and breaking when nothing is available was bad idea.

I can't figure out how could I possibly tell the client if theres still data available without having to send each slice of data as new packet with opcode etc., or is it even possible?

I am also wondering if theres better way to send whole buffer than below

```
while(channel.write(buffer) > 0);
```

Comment: I've answered part of this but I must say I don't understand what you mean by "there have to be breaks in file transfer some time" and "reading the data constantly and breaking when nothing is available was bad idea". Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to copy channels via buffers is as follows:

```
while (in.read(buffer) >= 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
  buffer.flip();
  out.write(buffer);
  buffer.compact();
}
```

This takes care of all the corner cases including read length != write length and having data left over at the end of the input.

NB that is for blocking mode. If you are in non-blocking mode you should return to the `select()` loop if read() or write() returns zero.

Comment: Wish I could accept multiple answers, because I am not sure at all to whose does this accept belong to. Vizier offered me a perfect solution but you fulfilled it. I am currently using almost exact code as yours and its working perfectly. Thanks so much for both of you. Yet I am not sure what does compact operation do, but I guess it must be better than clearing. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ruuhkis `compact()` removes the stuff that has been written but leaves anything that hasn't been written. If you use `clear()` instead you are risking data loss if the read length != the write length, which can happen any time.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
channel.transferFrom(0, fc.size(), fc);
```

Comment: Wow, how could have I missed that? I'll try that tomorrow and hopefully come to accept your answer if it works fine.

Comment: @Ruuhkis Please note that you need to call this method in a loop, as it isn't guaranteed to transfer the entire length in one invocation. See also my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot depend on the socket to remain open, there's no way around building a recover-and-continue mechanism into your protocol. As for telling the client how many bytes to expect, you can find the size of a file without reading it into memory using [`File.length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29).